# Get preceding sibling that attends condition in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the a XML file with the following data as example:

```
<file name="path\to\file1\">
</file>
<file name="path\to\file2\">
<error line="10" message="This file has an error"/>
</file>
<file name="path\to\file3\">
</file>
<file name="path\to\file4\">
<error line="15" message="This file has an error too"/>
</file>
```

Now suppose that I'm on the "file4" node. I want to get the first preceding sibling that has an error line, which is "file2" in this case, but in the real XML I won't know its position.

Is that a way that I can do this check using the `preceding-sibling` axis?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to get the first preceding sibling that has an error line

I am not sure what exactly "get" means in this context, but you can certainly *select* the first preceding sibling file that has an error line using:

```
select="preceding-sibling::file[error][1]"
```

Comment: Well that was simple.. Works like a charm, Thanks!